# how to move vertices more like in sculpting?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices

I'm new to blender and still lacking deep knowledge...

I'm trying to move a lot of individual vertices manually along one plane (like ZY plane for example).

It's super tedious to `G` + `shift x` every single time I select a vertex.

in other programs I used to have a neat tool I can just select and make "sticky" so I'm always in the same editing mode the moment I click the vertex.

Is there a trick?

Comment: depending on your needs there might be different solutions. if you are moving vertices on a ZY plane you can go to side view by pressing 3  and move  freely, you won't move anything in the X axis.

what mode in what other program are you referring to? that should help me get closer to what you mean.

Comment: You can use Shift + R to reuse your last action.  It’s not exactly what your looking for but it can be incredibly handy for repetitious tasks.

Comment: Blender moves parallel to the current view. If you press 3 to go to right view you will only move on the XY axis.  If you are moving single verts at a time you can just click-drag instead of pressing G.

Comment: you could try also using proportional editing mode (try various falloff curves)